# BoxGeometry segments

Tags: three.js

According to [BoxGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry) docs `widthSegments`, `heightSegments` and `depthSegments` are used to set a number of segmented faces along a corresponding side.

What is a real use case for these options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reason to use these options is to apply [Displacement mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping).

Basically you add vertices by subdiving face into segments (rectangles for box). By default each face of a cube has only one segment. The more details you want on the face of a cube, the more segments needed.

For other reason, you can do something like [this](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gridboxgeometry/1420?u=prisoner849)

Comment: Displacement and many other interesting things. For example, [this one](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gridboxgeometry/1420?u=prisoner849).

Comment: @prisoner849 thank you! I'll add the link to my answer